# Jquery Grid select all is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've implemented jquery grid on the project, the edit function on a particular row or checkbox, and click on the edit button, it will open a modal and it works as expected, but when I click on the select all checkbox and click on edit button it will not open modal.

I've attached a code snippet below please have a look at it, and I've attached a screenshot

```
<table id="capacityTable" border="0" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
    <td bgcolor="#aaaaaaaaa"><script type="text/javascript">
    'use strict';
        var currentPageNumber;
        var iDOfSelectedRows = [];
        $(document).ready(function()
        {
            var capacityArray = [
            <%
                String startDateTimeOfRPNow = "";
                String endDateTimeOfRPNow = "";
                int totalCount = 0;
                int remainingCount = 0;
                int fUsed = 0;
                int id = 0;
                int rpTimeSlotId = 0;
                if(capacities!=null)
                {
                    for (CapacityDetails capacitydetails : capacities) 
                    {
                        startDateTimeOfRPNow = capacitydetails.getStartTime();
                        endDateTimeOfRPNow = capacitydetails.getEndTime();
                        totalCount = Integer.parseInt(capacitydetails.getTotalCount());
                        remainingCount = Integer.parseInt(capacitydetails.getRemainingCount());
                        rpTimeSlotId = Integer.parseInt(capacitydetails.getRpTimeslotId());

                        if ((totalCount - remainingCount) > 0)
                        {
                            float fPercentage = ((float)totalCount - (float)remainingCount)/(float)totalCount;
                            fPercentage = (fPercentage)*100;

                            fUsed = (int)Math.round(fPercentage);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            fUsed = 0;
                        }
            %>
                        {
                            sDateTime : "<%=startDateTimeOfRPNow%>",
                            eDateTime : "<%=endDateTimeOfRPNow%>",
                            trpCount : "<%=totalCount%>",
                            rrpCount : "<%=remainingCount%>",
                            rpTimeSlotId : "<%=rpTimeSlotId%>",
                            <%
                                if(totalCount!=0)
                                {
                            %>
                                    rrpPerc: 100;   
                            <%
                                }
                                else
                                {
                            %>
                                rrpPerc: 0;
                            <%
                                }
                            %>
                        },
                    <%
                        id = id +1;
                            }   
                        }
                    %>
                    ],
                    idsOfSelectedRows = [];

                    function fnTimeSlot(id,rpTimeSlotId,startDateTimeSlot,endDateTimeSlot,totalCount,remainingCount) 
                    {
                        this.id = id;
                        this.rpTimeSlotId = rpTimeSlotId;
                        this.sDateTime=startDateTimeSlot;
                        this.eDateTime=endDateTimeSlot;
                        this.trpCount=totalCount;
                        this.rrpCount=remainingCount;
                    }

                    var _rpNowTable = $("#rpNowTable");
                    _rpNowTable.jqGrid
                    ({
                        datatype    :'local',
                        data        :capacityArray,
                        colNames    : ['TimeSlot Id','Start Date Time(UTC)','End Date Time(UTC)','Total Capacity','Remaining Capacity','Capacity Usage(%)'],
                        colModel    :[
                            {name:'rpTimeSlotId', index:'rpTimeSlotId', width: 40, align: 'center',sortable:false, hidden: true},
                            {name:'sDateTime', index:'sDateTime', width:40,sortable:false,align:"center"},
                            {name:'eDateTime', index:'eDateTime', width:40,sortable:false,align:"center"},
                            {name:'trpCount', index:'trpCount', width:20,sortable:false,align:"center"},
                            {name:'rrpCount', index:'rrpCount', width:20,sortable:false,align:"center"},
                            {name:'rrpPerc', index:'rrpPerc', width:40,sortable:false,align:"left",cellattr: function () {
                                                                return 'style="white-space: normal; height:90%;"'
                                                                }}
                        ],
                        rowNum      :50,
                        viewrecords :true, 
                        height      :'120%',
                        width       :700,
                        rownumbers  : false,
                        multiselect : true,
                        autowidth   : 1,
                        emptyDataText:'No capacity available for selected date',
                        altRows     :true,
                        altclass    :'myAltRowClass',
                        hidegrid    : false,
                        onSelectRow: function (id, isSelected)
                        {
                            currentPageNumber = $(".ui-pg-input").val();
                            var index = $.inArray(id, idsOfSelectedRows);

                            var _id=id;
                            var _rpTimeSlotId = $(this).getCell(id,'rpTimeSlotId');
                            var _startDate=$(this).getCell(id,'sDateTime');
                            var _endDate=$(this).getCell(id,'eDateTime');
                            var _totalCount=$(this).getCell(id,'trpCount');
                            var _remainingCount=$(this).getCell(id,'rrpCount');

                            if (!isSelected && index >= 0)
                            {
                                idsOfSelectedRows.splice(index, 1); 
                                iDOfSelectedRows.splice(index, 1);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                idsOfSelectedRows.push(id);
                                var obj=new fnTimeSlot(_id, _rpTimeSlotId, _startDate,_endDate,_totalCount,_remainingCount);
                                iDOfSelectedRows.push(obj);
                            }
                        }
                    }); //jqGrid() ends here
                });// ready() ends here         
                </script>
                <table border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="4" id="rpNowTable" name="rpNowTable"></table>
                <div id="pager"></div></td>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="4">&nbsp; </td>
            </tr>
            <tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
                <td class="btn-center" colspan="12">
                 <input type="button" class="InputButton" value="Add/Update Capacity" id="btnEditSession" name="btnEditSession" onClick="updateTotalCapacity(this.form,iDOfSelectedRows)">
                 </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

[Black mark is select all checkbox which is not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SNDMm.png)

[This is the button at the end of grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IAChE.png)

[On Click of edit/add button it will open a modal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/635kh.png)

Comment: The question is - where is this edit button and what this button do - i.e what is the code behind this button and which version of jqGrid is used - Guriddo jqGrid, free-jqGrid or jqGrid ver <=4.7

Comment: Current jquery version is 1.6.1 and edit button is at the end of grid, once it is submitted it will open a modal window to capture values, i've added one more screenshot in the question

Comment: JQGrid version is 4.3.2, Jquery-UI is 1.10.4, blockUI-2.37.js

Comment: What I mean is to post the code where you bind the click for the modal. As I say pictures does not help - code is needed. The best will be if you can prepare a online demo, by example in jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have used "multiselect: true" so you can use as below option which will create the column with checkboxs in the grid All functionality which you try to implement seems be directly in the grid.

There are callbacks onSelectRow and onSelectAll (or events jqGridSelectRow and jqGridSelectAll) which you can use

```
ids= [];
ids.push("<%=totalCount%>");
onSelectAll : function (ids, isSelected)
                        {
                            currentPageNumber = $(".ui-pg-input").val();
                            var index = $.inArray(ids, idsOfSelectedRows);
var count= 0;
                                        for(var rowCount=ids.slice(0)[0]; rowCount<=ids.slice(-1)[0];rowCount++){
                            var _id=ids.slice(count)[0];;
                            var _rpTimeSlotId = $(this).getCell(ids.slice(count)[0];,'rpTimeSlotId');
                            var _startDate=$(this).getCell(ids.slice(count)[0];,'sDateTime');
                            var _endDate=$(this).getCell(ids.slice(count)[0];,'eDateTime');
                            var _totalCount=$(this).getCell(ids.slice(count)[0];,'trpCount');
                            var _remainingCount=$(this).getCell(ids.slice(count)[0];,'rrpCount');

                            if (!isSelected && index >= 0)
                            {
                                idsOfSelectedRows.splice(index, 1); 
                                iDOfSelectedRows.splice(index, 1);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                idsOfSelectedRows.push(id);
                                var obj=new fnTimeSlot(_id, _rpTimeSlotId, _startDate,_endDate,_totalCount,_remainingCount);
                                iDOfSelectedRows.push(obj);
                            }
count++;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

After refactoring the code, I'm able to get select all in jqgrid

```
<table id="capacityTable" border="0" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
<td bgcolor="#aaaaaaaaa"><script type="text/javascript">
'use strict';
    var currentPageNumber;
    var iDOfSelectedRows = [];
    ids= [];
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        var capacityArray = [
        <%
            String startDateTimeOfRPNow = "";
            String endDateTimeOfRPNow = "";
            int totalCount = 0;
            int remainingCount = 0;
            int fUsed = 0;
            int id = 0;
            int rpTimeSlotId = 0;
            if(capacities!=null)
            {
                for (CapacityDetails capacitydetails : capacities) 
                {
                    startDateTimeOfRPNow = capacitydetails.getStartTime();
                    endDateTimeOfRPNow = capacitydetails.getEndTime();
                    totalCount = Integer.parseInt(capacitydetails.getTotalCount());
                    remainingCount = Integer.parseInt(capacitydetails.getRemainingCount());
                    rpTimeSlotId = Integer.parseInt(capacitydetails.getRpTimeslotId());

                    if ((totalCount - remainingCount) > 0)
                    {
                        float fPercentage = ((float)totalCount - (float)remainingCount)/(float)totalCount;
                        fPercentage = (fPercentage)*100;

                        fUsed = (int)Math.round(fPercentage);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        fUsed = 0;
                    }
        %>
                    {
                        sDateTime : "<%=startDateTimeOfRPNow%>",
                        eDateTime : "<%=endDateTimeOfRPNow%>",
                        trpCount : "<%=totalCount%>",
                        rrpCount : "<%=remainingCount%>",
                        rpTimeSlotId : "<%=rpTimeSlotId%>",
                        ids: ids.push("<%=id%>"),
                        <%
                            if(totalCount!=0)
                            {
                        %>
                                rrpPerc: 100;   
                        <%
                            }
                            else
                            {
                        %>
                            rrpPerc: 0;
                        <%
                            }
                        %>
                    },
                <%
                    id = id +1;
                        }   
                    }
                %>
                ],
                idsOfSelectedRows = [];

                function fnTimeSlot(id,rpTimeSlotId,startDateTimeSlot,endDateTimeSlot,totalCount,remainingCount) 
                {
                    this.id = id;
                    this.rpTimeSlotId = rpTimeSlotId;
                    this.sDateTime=startDateTimeSlot;
                    this.eDateTime=endDateTimeSlot;
                    this.trpCount=totalCount;
                    this.rrpCount=remainingCount;
                }

                var _rpNowTable = $("#rpNowTable");
                _rpNowTable.jqGrid
                ({
                    datatype    :'local',
                    data        :capacityArray,
                    colNames    : ['TimeSlot Id','Start Date Time(UTC)','End Date Time(UTC)','Total Capacity','Remaining Capacity','Capacity Usage(%)'],
                    colModel    :[
                        {name:'rpTimeSlotId', index:'rpTimeSlotId', width: 40, align: 'center',sortable:false, hidden: true},
                        {name:'sDateTime', index:'sDateTime', width:40,sortable:false,align:"center"},
                        {name:'eDateTime', index:'eDateTime', width:40,sortable:false,align:"center"},
                        {name:'trpCount', index:'trpCount', width:20,sortable:false,align:"center"},
                        {name:'rrpCount', index:'rrpCount', width:20,sortable:false,align:"center"},
                        {name:'rrpPerc', index:'rrpPerc', width:40,sortable:false,align:"left",cellattr: function () {
                                                            return 'style="white-space: normal; height:90%;"'
                                                            }}
                    ],
                    rowNum      :50,
                    viewrecords :true, 
                    height      :'120%',
                    width       :700,
                    rownumbers  : false,
                    multiselect : true,
                    autowidth   : 1,
                    emptyDataText:'No capacity available for selected date',
                    altRows     :true,
                    altclass    :'myAltRowClass',
                    hidegrid    : false,
                    onSelectRow: function (id, isSelected)
                    {
                        currentPageNumber = $(".ui-pg-input").val();
                        var index = $.inArray(id, idsOfSelectedRows);

                        var _id=id;
                        var _rpTimeSlotId = $(this).getCell(id,'rpTimeSlotId');
                        var _startDate=$(this).getCell(id,'sDateTime');
                        var _endDate=$(this).getCell(id,'eDateTime');
                        var _totalCount=$(this).getCell(id,'trpCount');
                        var _remainingCount=$(this).getCell(id,'rrpCount');

                        if (!isSelected && index >= 0)
                        {
                            idsOfSelectedRows.splice(index, 1); 
                            iDOfSelectedRows.splice(index, 1);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            idsOfSelectedRows.push(id);
                            var obj=new fnTimeSlot(_id, _rpTimeSlotId, _startDate,_endDate,_totalCount,_remainingCount);
                            iDOfSelectedRows.push(obj);
                        }
                    },
                    onSelectAll: function (id, isSelected)
                    {
                        currentPageNumber = $(".ui-pg-input").val();
                        var index = $.inArray(id, idsOfSelectedRows);

                        var count= 0;
                        for(var rowCount=ids.slice(0)[0]; rowCount<=ids.slice(-1)[0];rowCount++)
                            {
                                var _id=ids.slice(count)[0];
                                var _rpTimeSlotId = $(this).getCell(ids.slice(count)[0],'rpTimeSlotId');
                                var _startDate=$(this).getCell(ids.slice(count)[0],'sDateTime');
                                var _endDate=$(this).getCell(ids.slice(count)[0],'eDateTime');
                                var _totalProctorCount=$(this).getCell(ids.slice(count)[0],'trpCount');
                                var _remainingProctorCount=$(this).getCell(ids.slice(count)[0],'rrpCount');

                                if (!isSelected && index >= 0)
                                {
                                    idsOfSelectedRows.splice(index, 1); 
                                    iDOfSelectedRows.splice(index, 1);
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    idsOfSelectedRows.push(id);
                                    var obj=new fnRemoteProctorTimeSlot(_id, _rpTimeSlotId, _startDate,_endDate,_totalProctorCount,_remainingProctorCount);
                                    iDOfSelectedRows.push(obj);
                                }
                            count++;
                            }
                        }
                }); //jqGrid() ends here
            });// ready() ends here         
            </script>
            <table border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="4" id="rpNowTable" name="rpNowTable"></table>
            <div id="pager"></div></td>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4">&nbsp; </td>
        </tr>
        <tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
            <td class="btn-center" colspan="12">
             <input type="button" class="InputButton" value="Add/Update Capacity" id="btnEditSession" name="btnEditSession" onClick="updateTotalCapacity(this.form,iDOfSelectedRows)">
             </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```